# What's a valid reason to use an 'out' or 'ref' parameter in a method?

Tags: c#

I despise out's and ref's as parameters on methods. IMHO, they make code less clean and provide opportunities for side-effects. But I concede that I may not understand their usefulness which might explain part of my loathing. Please, can someone explain a valid case for out's or ref's?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between the two, or what is the purpose of using either of them in general? And why is this tagged java?

Comment: How do you think they provide opportunities for side-effects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp

Comment: I guess you need to get serious with C++ to understand why it exists, irregardless of its C# applications

Comment: The most common example of usage I run into in .NET is [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) ... I'd argue this case is more cleanly handled by an Option/Maybe type and decomposition/pattern-matching, but the question is about C# and Dictionary is a "common/shared/base" .NET runtime class: that is, can't forget backwards compatibility, must work nicely in overall language/CLR design, and have a need to support VB.NET and other similar languages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Basically if you need to return more than one value, it's an alternative to using something like `Tuple<,>` or a custom type to encapsulate the values. The canonical example is probably `int.TryParse` and related methods. They want to convey two pieces of information back:

- The parsed value
- Whether or not parsing succeeded.

Now these could *actually* have been written using a return type of `int?` etc in this case, but it's the same principle for other cases. (For example, `Dictionary<,>.TryGetValue`, where the value stored in the dictionary may legitimately be null.)

I wouldn't say I *despise* `out` and `ref` parameters, but I do believe they should only be used occasionally, and only when there isn't a better alternative. Most of the uses of `ref` I see on Stack Overflow are due to a misunderstanding of parameter passing.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Much the same, but you want the variable available as input as well. It's a bit like having an "in" parameter and another "out" parameter, except the caller can't separate the two :)

Comment: Sorry a question, Why .net team decided use `out` in tryparse not `ref`?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: Because the method doesn't need to know the existing value of the variable at all - why force the caller to pass in a value which isn't going to be used? The only benefit would be that it could be left with its current value on failure.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so ref is not good sample for this case, +1 for your help in comments

Comment: Good explanation. I still hate outs and refs. An out param can't beat the expressiveness and clarity of a well named class.

Answer (score 7):

`out` provides a way to return more than one value. `ref` is the same, except that you can *also* pass in a value.

Note that you can mutate an object even if is declared without `ref` (assuming it is mutable in the first place of course).

The alternative I prefer to `out` is to make a class to contain all the return values and return a single instance of that class.

Comment: "out" parameters certainly do provide an opportunity for side effects -- they require that the method either run forever, terminate abnormally, *or mutate a variable*. That's a side effect.

Answer (score 6):

The "new" (C# 4.0) `lock` uses the `ref` (technically the `lock` statement is syntactic sugar for the new [Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289498.aspx) overload). It wouldn't be possible to do it without :-)

```
bool acquiredLock = false;

try
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject, ref acquiredLock);

    // Code that accesses resources that are protected by the lock.

}
finally
{
    if (acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

so there is space for the `ref` in highly critical places.

The reason why simply returning a bool value wouldn't be enough is that an exception could occur between the `return true` of the `Monitor.Enter` and the `bool acquiredLock =` leaving your program with the question "was the lock tacken?" With the `ref` parameter this problem is solved.

Comment: However, why not `var acquiredLock = Monitor.Enter(lockObject)`? I reject this is as being a *good need* for `ref`, although it is used. Arguably the standard `Dictionary.TryGetValue` is a better example as it has *two* values that must be returned (key found and value).

Comment: @pst: Read the last paragraph again. You can't *return* whether the lock was taken because there might be an exception *between* when the return value was put "on the stack" and when the return value was copied into the variable.

Comment: @EricLippert, just curious: why does the `Monitor.Enter` method use `ref` and not `out`? While I know that they are the same at the IL level, this still requires that the programmer actually initializes the boolean, which seems pointless. Is there a reason or was this as simple oversight?

Comment: @Lucero Because an `out` wouldn't guarantee initialization. There could be an exception after the `try` and before the `Monitor.Enter`. What would be the value of `acquiredLock`?

Comment: @Lucero I'll add that if you try to write something like '`bool b; try { MyTest(out b); } finally { if (b) { } }` you'll get `Use of unassigned local variable 'b'`

Answer (score 2):

They're pretty much the same - the only difference is that a variable you pass as an `out` parameter doesn't need to be initialised, and the method using the `out` parameter has to set it to something.

```
int x;
Foo(out x); 

int y;
Foo(ref y);
```

`Ref` parameters are for data that might be modified, `out` parameters are for data that's an additional output for the function (eg `int.TryParse`) that are already using the return value for something.

Comment: Is that true? What error do you get when a ref is not intialised?

Comment: Also OP asked for their usage in .net (by knowing that good alternatives are available) not their difference,

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: it certainly is true, and if you want to know what error you get, fire up the compiler and find out.