# Generics and types values in my method show error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics, casting

I'm trying to write a generic method, and the code below gives errors.

> Cannot convert type '`T2`' to '`T1`'
>
> '`T1`' does not contain a definition for 'Action' and no extension
>   method 'Action' accepting a first  argument of type '`T1`' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
private List<T2> FillChildControlOnSave<T1, T2>(
        ref T1 objEntity, ref List<T1> _entityParent, ref List<T2> _entityDetail)
{
    foreach (T2 c in _entityDetail)
    {
        if (c.Action == XERP.Entity.ActionMode.Add)            
            objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c);

        var tmp = objEntity.PlnBOMDetails
                     .Where(p => p.BOMDetailRecordID == c.BOMDetailRecordID && 
                                 p.BOMID == c.BOMID && 
                                 p.IsDeleted == false)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

        if (tmp != null)
           if (c.Action == Entity.ActionMode.Delete)            
               objController.Context.PlnBOMDetails.DeleteObject(tmp);            
    }

    return _entityDetail;

}
```

If I replace `T1` and `T2` with `PlnBOMMaster,PlnBOMDetail` then above syntax works fine. How to solve this generic method  problem?

Comment: Notice: using `ref` is not very good idea. Underscore in parameter names is not very good idea. You are not using `_entityParent` parameter in your code. You don't need to pass `List` if you are only enumerating it. You don't need to use generics if you are working with concrete object properties. Just program to some abstraction instead (interface or base class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict `T1` and `T2` to certain classes or interfaces, you need to use [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), like this:

```
private List<T2> FillChildControlOnSave<T1, T2>(ref T1 objEntity, 
                                                ref List<T1> _entityParent, 
                                                ref List<T2> _entityDetail)
    where T1 : PinBOMMaster
    where T2 : PinBOMDetail
{
    ...
}
```

Of course `PinBOMMaster` and `PinBOMDetail` can be replaced with an appropriate interface, such as this:

```
public interface IMaster<TDetail>
    where TDetail : IDetail
{
    List<TDetail> Details { get; }
}

public interface IDetail
{
    int RecordID { get; }
    int BOMID { get; }
    bool isDeleted { get; }
    Entity.ActionMode Action { get; set; }
}

public class PinBOMMaster : IMaster<PinBOMDetail>
{
    ...
}

public class PinBOMDetail : IDetail
{
    ...
}

private List<T2> FillChildControlOnSave<T1, T2>(ref T1 objEntity, 
                                                ref List<T1> _entityParent, 
                                                ref List<T2> _entityDetail)
    where T1 : IMaster<T2>
    where T2 : IDetail
{
    ...
}
```

*Note:* if your entities are created by a code generation tool, you'll have to use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to apply the interface implementations.

Of course, you probably can't use `objController.Context.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c)`. You'll have to replace it with generic code, like this:

```
// for DbContext
objController.Context.Set<T2>().Add(c);

// for ObjectContext
objController.Context.CreateObjectSet<T2>().AddObject(c);
```

Of course, you can also write your own method to do this. For example, the `IDetail` / `IMaster` interfaces could have an `AddToContext(...)` method which takes the context and inserts itself into the appropriate collection. Then in `FillChildControlOnSave` you just call `c.AddToContext(objConctroller.Context);`.

Comment: But in this case we don't need generics, don't we? :)

Comment: There could still be a use for generics even in that case -- e.g. if you want the return type to exactly match the input type.

Comment: p.s.w.g   thanks for reply,I can not use PlnBOMMaster, PlnBOMDetail
in where statement because,it’s a common method ,I need to use this method in several time with my several entities

Comment: @shamim the same principle applies, although you'll have to create interfaces for your entities. See my updated answer.

Comment: p.s.w.g will you please fix this code syntax objController.Context.Set<T2>()
.I don’t get any Set Method in context

Comment: @shamim I'm not sure what ORM you're using. [`Set<T2>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.103).aspx) is a method from Entity Framework's `DbContext` class.

Comment: p.s.w.g thanks for reply.I use EF 4.0 uses the ObjectContext.my question code syntax objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c); also need to corporate in generic method,help me to replace this syntax with generic one.thanks again

Comment: @shamim I've included more details in my answer for completeness.

Comment: p.s.w.g thanks for reply also thask for your new syntax ,my problem remains i apply your new context code in my delete condition but in add and update hope you see my problem description code there  i need to bind child object with parent object  not  add or update occur  directly with  the context ,because after execute this method i need to work on parent object ,there i also need to get the child object too.so i bind child object with parent by using the sytax  objEntity.PlnBOMDetails.Add(c); for this generic method i need to replace this syntax with generic one.thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to invoke members on instances of `T1` and `T2` then you have to tell the compiler something about those types:

```
private T2 Bar<T1,T2>(T1 actionable) where T1 : IActionable, T2 : IActionResult
{
    T2 result = actionable.Action();
    return result;
}
```

You can specify constraints on `T1` and `T2` using the `where` keyword after the method's arguments.

You can also specify things such as:

```
where T : new()  // has a default constructor
where T : struct // is a value type
where T : class  // is a reference type
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping throught a list of `T2` with this line :

```
foreach (T2 c in _entityDetail)
```

Then you are accessing the property `Detail` of `c` in this line :

```
if (c.Action == XERP.Entity.ActionMode.Add)
```

How the compiler could know that the type `T2` contain such a property?

You need to constraint the generic to be one kind of interface like this:

```
interface IPlnBOMDetail { XERP.Entity.ActionMode Action {get;}}
class PlnBOMDetail : IPlnBOMDetail {}

private List<T2> FillChildControlOnSave<T1, T2>(ref T1 objEntity, ref List<T1> _entityParent, ref List<T2> _entityDetail)
    where T2 : IPlnBOMDetail
```

The same for all the rest of your code.

A side note: using `ref` parameter is a code smell.
I advise you to read this topic : [When to use ref and when it is not necessary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp).
TL;DR : [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) said

> you almost never need to use ref/out

Comment: Scorpi0 thanks for reply,I can not use PlnBOMMaster, PlnBOMDetail
in where statement because,it’s a common method ,I need to use this method in several time with my several entities

Comment: @shamim in that case you need to get those types to implement interfaces which provide the required operations, then constrain your type parameters to those interfaces. It's either that or do some truly horrible things with reflection or the DLR to go hunting for a method which may or may not exist (and sacrifice type safety along the way).