# Passing a reference by reference

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

How could it be any useful to pass a reference object by reference. The regular usage is as the following:

```
public static void main()
{
    Student st = new Student();
    st.FirstName = "Marc";
    PutLastName(st);
    Console.WriteLLine(st.FirstName + " " + st.LastName);
}

public static PutLastName(Student student)
{
    student.LastName = "Anthony";
}
```

Why would anybody write the following, which does the same thing and does print: "Marc Anthony":

```
public static void main()
{
    Student st = new Student();
    st.FirstName = "Marc";
    PutLastName(ref st);
    Console.WriteLLine(st.FirstName + " " + st.LastName);
}

public static PutLastName(ref Student student)
{
    student.LastName = "Anthony";
}
```

Comment: This is basically a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp. You should consider just reading the documentation for `ref` to understand the difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx. Granted, I don't think there are common reasons for using `ref` so your brain might have a hard time accepting that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't do the same thing.. under the hood.

Functionally, it works the same, yes. Under the hood though.. the reference itself is being passed when using `ref`. Without `ref`, the reference value is copied.

Think of references as memory pointers. `student` has the value `1134`.. a memory address. When you don't use `ref`, `1134` is applied to a new reference.. pointing at the same memory address.

Using `ref` can have dangerous consequences when you realise the above. For example, consider this:

```
public static void PutLastName(Student student)
{
    student = new Student();
    student.LastName = "Whitehead";
}

// .. calling code ..
Student st = new Student();
st.FirstName = "Marc";
st.LastName = "Anthony";
PutLastName(st);
Console.WriteLLine(st.FirstName + " " + st.LastName); // "Marc Anthony"
```

Whereas, using `ref`:

```
public static void PutLastName(ref Student student)
{
    student = new Student();
    student.FirstName = "Simon";
    student.LastName = "Whitehead";
}

// .. calling code ..
Student st = new Student();
st.FirstName = "Marc";
st.LastName = "Anthony";
PutLastName(ref st);
Console.WriteLLine(st.FirstName + " " + st.LastName); // "Simon Whitehead"
```

Using `ref` physically changed the reference. Without it.. you're just telling a different reference to point somewhere else (which is void once the function steps out). So, when using `ref`, you're giving the callee the ability to physically change the reference itself.. not just the memory it points at.

Comment: I have perfectly understood the difference, and you hit the heart of the truth when you said that using ref can be dangerous. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In the second version the ref means that PutLastName can change st.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference by reference allows you to not only edit the referenced data, but also allows you to change the object it is referring to itself.

The difference is in these uses:

```
// from the Main's point of view, this function does absolutely nothing
public static PutLastName(Student student)
{
    student = new Student();
}

// This would clear Main's student.
public static PutLastName(ref Student student)
{
    student = new Student();
}
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Basically, passing by reference (`ref` or `out`) does the same thing regardless of type (reference type or other types) -- it allows an assignment to the parameter in the function to have the same effect as an assignment to the original passed variable in the calling scope. This can never happen when not passing by reference.