# Passing reference type in C#

Tags: c#

```
class Test
{
    static void Func(StringBuilder myString)
    {
        myString.Append ("test");
        myString = null;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
        Func(s1);
        Console.WriteLine (s1);
    }
}
```

The output is "Test", why isn't it null?

If s1 is passed ***by reference*** to Func(), then why does `myString.Append("test")` change it, but `myString = null` does not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This horse has been beaten to death already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18649121/465495

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> if s1 is passed by reference to Func(), then why does
>   myString.Append("test") does change it

Its not passed by references, instead its address value is passed to the function.

Suppose `S1` is pointing to a memory location 0x48, This will be passed to `Func`, where `Func` parameter `myString` will start pointing to that location. Later when you `Append` a text to that location, it gets added. But later when you assign `null` to `myString`, it starts pointing to nothing, but the original location remains unchanged.

You should see: [Parameter passing in C# by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Consider the following diagrams. 
In Step 1, you create a new object of type `StringBuilder` and let `S1` refers to that object.

[image]

In Step 2, after passing `S1` to `Func`, now `myString` also points to the same object in memory.

[image]

Later when you `Append`, text through `myString`, it updates the original object, since `myString` is pointing to the memory location held by the object.

In Step 3, when you assign null to the `myString` it looses the address for `StringBuilder` object, but this doesn't change anything in the object or the pointer `S1`.

[image]

Comment: Your explanation is a bit confusing, but upvoted for the link.

Comment: @Dan, just added some diagrams to clarify

Comment: @Habib What do you use as a tool for this kind of diagrams? `+1` btw..

Comment: @SonerGönül, [Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/visio/)

Answer (score 12):

You're passing the reference to the object by value.

I.e. the address of the object is passed by value, but the address to the object and the object is the same. So when you call your method, the VM copies the reference; you're just changing a copy.

On `myString.Append` you're using the copied reference to get to the object (still only one object) which is then changed/invoked.

What you think you're doing is this:

```
class Test
{
    static void Func(ref StringBuilder myString)
    {
        myString.Append("test");
        myString = null;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder();
        Func(ref s1);
        Console.WriteLine(s1);
    }
}
```

A longer explanation: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 2):

In C#, the pointer (reference) to a complex type, by default, is passed by value. You must specify that it is passed by reference, like this:

```
static void Func(ref StringBuilder myString)
{
    myString.Append ("test");
    myString = null;
}
```

Comment: Complex types are passed by reference, the reference (pointer) itself is passed by value.

Comment: @Dan - answer updated to clarify that. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

add the `ref` to the function to pass it by ref.

```
static void Func(ref StringBuilder myString)
{
    myString.Append ("test");
    myString = null;
}
```

Then call it like:

```
Func(ref s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass a reference to your StringBuilder s1 to Func.
Inside Func, the reference to that same StringBuilder instance is called "myString".
You first tell it to do something ("`myString.Append("Test")`), then set the reference INSIDE Func to null. The result of Append is visible to Main(); the reference being set to null does not influence s1 in Main.