# Working with arrays/list with C# components in Grasshopper 3D

Tags: c#, grasshopper

New user of Grasshopper 3D here, and I am in need of some C# syntax help for coding in Grasshopper 3D.
I have a script, for example, that's pasted below:

```
public static int arraySum(int[] myArray){
    int someValue = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++){
       someValue += myArray[i];
    }
    return someValue;
}
```

The above static method sums all values of an array.

From my understanding of the scripting components of C# in Grasshopper, you cannot create static methods, as everything is a non-returning void method. You assign a variable (the output) as a psuedo-return, is that correct?

Knowing that - how do I implement my above script, for example, to a C# component?

Instead of having a "return", I simply assigned a variable, for example, A as the sum. But I ran into some issues there, for example, with some C# methods like .Length not working.

The format of a method in the C# component of Grasshopper 3D is the following:

```
private void RunScript(int x, ref object A){
}
```

Comment: Everytime I see a `ref`, the Baby Jesus in me cries a little...

Comment: @Brian Why so good sir?

Comment: `Ref` should be used _sparingly_ since it only passes a _reference to the object_ and not a copy of the object.  Please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp) and [this](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) article for a more in-depth explanation on the best practices for using it (and the `out` keyword too).

Comment: I have no choice, as that's what the C# component requires you to use, for example: http://puu.sh/5hgnz/7749da8d75.png

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old question, but I will go ahead and complete it for completion's sake.  In any GH Scripting component there are two zones to write code.  In the image you see the private method `RunScript` and the other area in `// <Custom Additional Code>`
[image]

So I could write your code within the RunScript method like this:

```
 private void RunScript(List<int> myArray, ref object A)
 {

    int someValue = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Count; i++){
      someValue += myArray[i];
    }

    A = someValue;

 }
```

Notice that I redefined myArray as a list of type int like on the script component input:
[image]

Since it is a list, I use `myArray.Count` in the loop.  Finally I use `A = someValue` to get the result in the output of the component.

I could also write the method in the `// <Custom additional code>` area as such:

```
  private void RunScript(List<int> myArray, ref object A)
  {

    A = arraySum(myArray.ToArray());

  }

  // <Custom additional code> 

  public static int arraySum(int[] myArray){
    int someValue = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++){
      someValue += myArray[i];
    }
    return someValue;
  }

  // </Custom additional code>
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

I change the incomming `myArray.ToArray()` since it comes in as a list to the component.  In this second manner, your original code is pretty much the same.

Hope this helps answer an old question!

Comment: This helped me when I was getting started and I forgot to upvote, there you go.