# external fill of parameters' function, help please

Tags: c#, .net, xml, oop

I have implemented a method that requires 2 parameters (arguments) : the first one is the source of the xml file ( type string) and the second one is the destination path of the generated pdf file (type string) 
This application will be used by another application that will assign automatically the 2 parameters.
My question is how should I declare the 2 arguments until I can assign external parameters?

in other meaning : I implemented a console appication . When calling it from cmd , it looks like that : C:> name_of_apllication "path1" "path2". How should I implement the parameters if the called method until they will replaced by "path1" and "path2"?

this is the code of the main class : the method that will be used is : GeneratePDF_CTAF

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = "";
            string output =  "";

            GeneratePDF.GeneratePDF_Ctaf( ref  input, ref  output );

        }
```

this is the error screen , it is in french and that means can not find file
[image]

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. If you want your function to accept two parameters, just declare them in the parameter list.

Comment: I implemented a console appication . When calling it from cmd , it looks like that : C:> name_of_apllication "path1" "path2". How should I implement the parameters if the called method until they will replaced by "path1" and "path2"?

Comment: See [Command Line Parameters Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial , but main main method calls the generatePDF_CTAF method that requires the 2 arguments

Comment: @user1503496 - This is a linking error.  You can't find a DLL. It has nothing to do with function parameters or xml or oop.  Review your linking options in visual studio.  Close visual studio and restart, re-install COM components etc.  Nothing to do with "programming".

Answer (score 1):

The command line arguments are passed to the `Main` method as an array of strings. This is the `args` parameter in your code, so you can simply extract the parameters you need from there:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length != 2) 
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("This program requires exactly 2 parameters");
        return 1; // error code
    }

    string input = args[0];
    string output = args[1];

    GeneratePDF.GeneratePDF_Ctaf(input, output);
    return 0; // no error
}
```

Note here, I've modified `Main` to return an `int`. A non-zero return value is often used in console applications to provide error information to the calling program. I've also removed the `ref` keyword from your parameters because [it's almost never necessary to use `ref` parameters in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp).

Comment: exception external limit oh the table ! it shows This program requires exactly 2 parameters

Comment: @user1503496 Did you execute it with command line arguments? If you're debugging in VS, make sure you set the command line arguments in the debug section of the project properties. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kf0yb05.aspx)

Comment: from the cmd , it shows me the exception : can not load the file publickeytocken = null

Comment: @user1503496 My guess is you tried to copy the `.exe` out and didn't copy all the `.dll` necessary files *or* you tried to execute it from outside that directory. Try `cd`-ing into the bin directory (the output of your VS build) and executing it from there.

Comment: this is what i had done :(

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something fundamental about using a function that you are not understanding so I will give a short example -- if it does not solve your problem please explain why not:

```
 void Main(string[] args)
 {
     aFunction(args[1], args[2]);

 }


 void aFunction(string arg1, string arg2)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(arg1);
    Console.WriteLine(arg2);
 }
```

Comment: exception external limit oh the table !

Comment: @user1503496 - This comment makes no sense.  Show your full code and the full error you are getting if you need any additonal help.  Modiy your question.