# Create and Show a WinForm

Tags: c#, forms, activator

I´m trying to create and show forms in VS 2013 with a generic method this is my method:

```
void showOrUpdateForm<T>(ref Form form) where T : Form 
{
    if (form == null)
    {
        form = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T;
        form.Show();
    }
    else
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    form.Focus();
}
```

this code i got it from here. So when i try to call this method like they told like that:

```
 myForm1 form;
 showOrUpdateForm<myForm1>(ref form);
```

It give me error:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'GestionEAS.GestionEAS.showOrUpdateForm(ref System.Windows.Forms.Form)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref package.Views.form' to 'ref System.Windows.Forms.Form'

How can I fix this?

Comment: side note: the `myForm1 form;` fragment is incorrect, since `form` contains *thrash*, not *null*; change it into `myForm1 form = null;`

Comment: "showOrUpdateForm<T>(ref Form form)" - Just a hint: there is no need to have the 'ref'. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp

Comment: Dmitry: its not a prb if I change it to myForm1 form = null; it gives me the same error.

Comment: thnx for the Hint Ulric ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that you want something like that:

```
// I'd rather return potentially created form directly (not via "ref")
// do you need "this" in the method? That's why "static"
static T showOrUpdateForm<T>(T form = null)
  where T: Form, new() {

  if (null == form) 
    form = new T(); // <- no Activator since "new()" constraint is declared

  form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  form.BringToFront(); // <- if the form is not a foreground one

  if (form.CanFocus) // <- better check than have an exception
    form.Focus();

  return form;
}
...
// more compact and readable
myForm1 form = showOrUpdateForm<myForm1>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a `myForm1` as a `ref Form`.
You should change that to a `ref T`, so that the parameter type matches the variable.

Also, you should add `, new()` to your generic constraints and replace `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T` with `new T()`

Comment: thnx for your answer but can explain to me more plz??

Comment: but how can I pass my Form in parameters I have many forms that i want to call them like that

Comment: @BHimura: By making the parameter generic.

Comment: for changing paramtere to ref T it gives me an error Error 3 The name 'T' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

How about this, will nicely cater for creating forms with different parameters

```
void showOrUpdateForm<T>(ref T form, Func<T> formCreator) where T : Form 
{
    if (form == null)
    {
        form = formCreator();
        form.Show();
    }
    else
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    if(form.CanFocus)
        form.Focus();
}
```

using it as . . .

```
MyForm myForm = null;
form1 = showOrUpdateForm(myForm, () => new MyForm());
```