# How to pass reference of model in ASP.net MVC 5 Function?

Tags: c#

I have a service with a function  `public bool UpdateSubClient(ref SubClient subClient)` which updates the database.

Subclient model is as follow

```
public string SubClientName { get; set; }
public string BtnText { get; set;}
public string HdrText { get; set; }
public string ReturnURL { get; set; }
```

I am trying to call the the UpdateSubclient as follows

```
SubClientService subclientservice = new SubClientService();
SubClient currentsubclient = new SubClient();
currentsubclient.SubClientName = form["SubClientName"].ToString();
currentsubclient.ClientID = Convert.ToInt32(form["ClientID"]);
currentsubclient.BtnText = form["BtnText"].ToString();
currentsubclient.HdrText = form["HdrText"].ToString();
currentsubclient.ReturnURL = form["ReturnURL"].ToString();
bool success = subclientservice.UpdateSubClient(currentsubclient);
```

I am getting invalid argument error and couldn't figure out the way to pass reference. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **What does the error say**?

Comment: @Slaks the error is `overloaded method has invalid argument`.

Comment: What is the declaration of SubClientService.UpdateSubClient? Is that the line that is throwing the error? Nevermind, see it at the top, you need to pass by reference, like subclientservice.UpdateSubClient(ref currentsubclient);

Comment: By the way, if you made the UpdateSubClient method, there really isn't a need for a "ref" declaration unless you intend to change the reference (create a new instance) of the type being passed in. You can modify the fields all you want and the changes will persist without the ref keyword.

Comment: @Rob Beyer the last line ` bool success = subclientservice.UpdateSubClient(currentsubclient);` is throwing error.

Comment: @DineshDevkota you need to include the `ref` keyword to match the method declaration. I would suggest reading this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Rob Beyer the class in which that function is, extends an interface. I really cannot use that hack to make it work.

Comment: Are you sure you *need* `ref`?

Comment: @user2864740 as I explained in comment before "the class in which that function is, extends an interface" I cannot really change it to make it work that way.

Comment: And `bool success = subclientservice.UpdateSubClient(ref currentsubclient)` doesn't "just work"?

Comment: I've removed the other keywords because there is nothing in the question and uses an ASP/MVC feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change request to other backend developers and changed the

```
public bool UpdateSubClient(ref SubClient subClient)
```

to

```
public bool UpdateSubClient(SubClient subClient)
```

to avoid any complications. Thanks  **@user2864740** insisting me to research on usages of ref as parameter.