# The list doesn't change in a method C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Items`, and I try to sort a list of items:

```
private static void Sort(List<Items> items)
{
.
.
.
   SortDesc(items);
}

private static void SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
}
```

When the debugger in `SortDesc()`, the items in the list are sorted by `Neto DESC`. When I continue and return back to `Sort()`, the list in back to how it was before I called `SortDesc()`.

The `List<T>` sending by default by ref, so why does this not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You are changing the reference in memory which the `items` is pointing with this line of code:

```
 items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
```

When you are calling the `SortDesc` method, list object is passed by reference. And then you are creating new list. After this you are setting it to `items` parameter. After this, `items` is pointing to the new reference, not the previous one. But, the real `items` is still pointing to the old one.

So, you must return newly created list:

```
private static List<Items> SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  return items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
}
```

And then, just set it in your `Sort` method:

```
items = SortDesc(items);
```

***P.S:*** You can also use `ref` keyword explicitly for the desired result, but this is not the preferred way actually. (`...void SortDesc(ref List<Items> items)`).
You can read [@JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) answer from his answer to that question [When to use ref and when it is not necessary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp):

> Useful answer: you almost never need to use ref/out. It's basically a
>   way of getting another return value, and should usually be avoided
>   precisely because it means the method's probably trying to do too
>   much.

Comment: sorry you were fast :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan Not problem. This happens in SO very often. :)

Comment: @Farhad Jabiyev, Why there is different between real items and old time? Is it not the same?

Comment: @OrK I didn't undertand what is your question. But, yes, you can use `ref`  explicitly if you want the desired result. But, actually this is not good design and it is not preferred way.

Comment: If I'm changing the pointer of "items" in SortDesc(), why is not changed in Sort()? After all, "items" is a reference type (class)..

Comment: @OrK - There's a difference between the reference to the list and references to the items in the list. When you create a new list the items inside can be in a different order to the original list.

Comment: @OrK Because, 'items' in `SortDesc` method is not `items` from the Sort method. It is just a reference. Try to change name of `items` for example to `inputList` and then rethink again. By `items = ...` line you are telling that `items` in `SortDesc` must point to another reference. But the real `items` is still pointing the old reference.

Comment: FarhadJabiyev ,Enigmativity, Now I understand.Thanks!

Comment: @OrK We are glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the ordered items,

```
private static  List<Items>  SortFromTheHighPriceToLowPriceByNeto(List<Items> items)
{
    items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `SortDesc` you pass a copy of the reference to the original `items` variable to the method. So in the method when you re-assign `item` you are assigning the new reference to a copy of the original reference and not the original reference itself. The original reference stays the same.

In order to update the original reference you need to pass `items` by reference. Do it like this:

```
private static void SortDesc(ref List<Items> items)
{
    items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
}
```

If you do it that way the call would become `SortDesc(ref items)`. This will work as expected.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Why? This method is a bit of an anomaly in its own right. It would be better to move the internals of this method to the calling code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Also, in this case, the OP is coming to grips with the difference between passing a reference by value and passing a reference by reference. If he can understand the distinction then he should be able to move on to understanding why it might not be the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> The `List<T>` sending by default by ref, so why does this not work?

No, all parameters that are not specially marked, are passed by value (and it goes for both reference types and value types). If you changed your method into `ref` it would work:

```
private static void SortDesc(ref List<Items> items)
{
  items = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
}
```

The point here, as was also explained in Farhad's answer, is that `.ToList()` creates a ***new*** instance of `List<Items>`. The old instance is unchanged. The assignment `items = ...` above changes the *value* of the reference (from referring the original instance to referring the new instance), so if the parameter is *by value* it will not work.

Since you make a new instance, it is probably better to just return it directly:

```
private static List<Items> SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  return items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
}
```

However, since you made your method `void`, maybe you wanted to sort the *same* list and not create *another* list?

In that case there are some possibilities. One is to use the `Sort` method on `List<>`, like this:

```
private static void SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  items.Sort((x, y) => y.Neto.CompareTo(x.Neto)); // unstable
}
```

or:

```
private static void SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  items.Sort((x, y) => Comparer<Xxx>.Default.Compare(y.Neto, x.Neto)); // unstable
}
```

where `Xxx` denotes the declared (compile-time) type of the `Neto` property. The first (simpler) of these two works fine if `.Neto` is never a null reference (including the case where `Xxx` is a value type).

These are descending because we swap `x` and `y` after the lambda arrow.

Warning: Unstable means that if some `Items` in the `List<>` have equally small `.Neto`, there is no telling what the order of these is going to be. This is **not** equivalent to the earlier examples which are stable.

If you need Linq `OrderByDescending` or need stable sort, you might try the following (although it is not pretty):

```
private static void SortDesc(List<Items> items)
{
  var tempList = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Neto).ToList();
  items.Clear();
  items.AddRange(tempList);
}
```

Instead of `Clear` and `AddRange` you can also copy the list entries explicitly with a `for` loop containing `items[i] = tempList[i]`.