# C# String pass by reference

Tags: c#, string, function, pass-by-reference

I am working on my first Windows Form App and I need to pass a string from one function to another. My code is rather long at this point so I made a small example that is reproducing the same error.

All that I am trying to do is take the created string from `Create()` and pass it into `Gets()`. I have done this with C++ but I cannot seem to figure it out with C#.

```
private void Create()
{
    string a;
    a = "This is a test";
    Gets(a);
}

private void Gets(string b)
{
    MessageBox.Show(b);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Gets();  //error CS1501: No overload for method 'Gets' takes 0 arguments
}
```

Comment: There is no code that calls "Create" function - not really clear what you trying to do. You may want to show version in C++ that demonstrates your goal.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Create();
}
```

You were trying to call the function `Gets()` , but it needs a parameter. If you call the function `Create()`, it will create the string and call `Gets()` with the created string , so now it can be displayed in the `MessageBox`.

Comment: I know I can cut out the middle man sort to speak and just call the Create method. I simplified the example for this post. I am trying to learn how to pass strings from 1 method to another and then call the 2nd method when needed. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Your stated error has nothing to do with passing a string by reference - as a C++ developer you should be able to understand the error.

You have one method called `Gets` that takes a string parameter. You then call it without a string, so the compiler rightfully complains that there is no overload for the method that takes no parameter.

Your solution is to either pass a string (or null) to the existing method, or create an overload that takes no parameters. Be aware that if you pass a null then your MessageBox call will fail, so you may want to substitute a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is stating it cannot find a method named Gets that takes 0 arguments.

This is the signature of your method:

```
private void Gets(string b)
```

That means to call it, you need to pass one argument of type `string` to it. Therefore, you need to do this when you are calling it:

```
Gets("hello or whatever you want");
```

You almost never, though there are times, need to pass an argument by `ref`. There are rare cases where you may need to, so perhaps refer  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp) answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for what I am looking to do.

Thank you everyone for your input.

```
        public string Create()
    {
        string a;

        a = "This is a test";

        return a;

    }


    private void Gets()
    {

        string Value = Create();
        MessageBox.Show(Value);

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Gets();
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems to me that you're trying to create some state in the `Create` method that you want to be able to use in the `Gets` method, however `Gets` is triggered from a button click. The answer, if that's the case, is to use a class-level variable to hold the state.

Try this:

```
private void Create()
{
    b = "This is a test";
}

private string b = null;
private void Gets()
{
    MessageBox.Show(b);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Gets();
}
```

Comment: you need more clarity from the OP before answering.

Comment: @SirajMansour - Why do you think so?