# Are there any downsides of in ref

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

I was just wondering where there any downsides to using `in` method argument from c# 7.2
I know this is recommended for dealing with Structs and they say it won't [increase performance that much](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types) but from what I can tell this won't have any negative impact on the code and might help you with stack overflow exceptions when doing recursions.
Dose anyone know of a good reason why all methods should not be marked as `in`?
[I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp) why people recommend to avoid `ref` and `out` but they don't work here.

Comment: With `in` you can explicitly tell the parameter won't be changed. So it depends on the situation i suppose

Comment: @EpicKip That what I was wondering what situation is not putting in on a parameter better? I am unable to think of any.

Comment: When it might be changed? Also when it being changed won't matter at all. Or where it clear that the parameter is just input, for example a `Create()` method usually will not alter the parameters so you wouldn't have to explicitly specify

Comment: for example, when reference is bigger than object itself, so making a copy is cheaper.

Comment: @Tigran That makes sense. Do you know of an situation when this might happen?

Comment: Think in C/C++ is easier if you know about it. The `in` is almost same with const pointer(reference). `ref` is non-const pointer(reference). It means that if not mark `in` or `ref`, the parameter will fully copy to stack again. Therefore it can cause stack overflow if the parameter size is huge. `in` does not allow to write the referencing memory. It is different with `ref`.

Comment: It was *meant* to help programmers write more efficient code.  But it is just as likely to produce less efficient code.  The refactoring is unpleasant, you have to rewrite a class to a struct, ensure that methods don't try to mutate it and focus on storing it in a local variable instead of the heap.  Bunch of work, you might still not be ahead.  Don't start on it until a profiler showed you a bottleneck.  The ref features, as well as Span, came out of Roslyn.  They had a tough job, beating a C++ version that was perf-tuned for over a decade with  immutable types in C# was not easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a performance related question, as a matter of discussion `in` was introduced for that reason, it's hard to find single, correct answer, without really measuring performance on concrete code sample.

But...

We know that `in` creates a reference which is `32bit` on x86 OS, and `64bit` on x64 OS.

Now consider a structure like

```
struct Token
{
    char x; 
}
```

on x64 OS, copy this structure on the stack, likely, will execute faster, than creating `64bit` reference to the same data.

Plus, do not forget, that `in` implies "constantness" on an instance, which goes beyond performance reasoning, and targets directly your design. Hence, while from performance related matters, some of reasoning might be arguable, from design point of view, `in` has distinct and clear semantics to target specific design use cases.