# List doesn't return value on function

Tags: c#, .net

I am using below method to get list. Although there are records on 'lc' it doesn't pass to the list .

```
public void assignList(List<list_chart> lc, DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
        {
            lc = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
                  where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
                  orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
                  select new list_chart
                  {
                      SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
                      Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
                  }).ToList();
        }

//lc has 100 records but listchart1 still shows 0 after i call method.
assignList(listchart1, dtMetric1, ucMetrics.CheckedItems[0].DisplayText);
```

What do i miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are assigning `lc` to a new object that's why on caller invoker the reference is still pointing to old address of list. To solve this, either you should return the `list` back from assignList method or use the list by Reference.

**Solution 1:** (Return the list)

```cs
public List<list_chart> assignList(List<list_chart> lc, DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
{
    lc = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
          where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
          orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
          select new list_chart
          {
              SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
              Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
          }).ToList();

      return lc;
}
```

**Solution 1.1** If you want to keep the record of `lc` intact then use below approach:

```cs
public void assignList(List<list_chart> lc, DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
{
    var result = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
          where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
          orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
          select new list_chart
          {
              SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
              Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
          }).ToList();

     lc.AddRange(result);

}
```

**Solution 2:** (List by Reference)

```cs
public void assignList(ref List<list_chart> lc, DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
{
    lc = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
          where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
          orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
          select new list_chart
          {
              SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
              Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
          }).ToList();
}
```

I would recommend you to use the **Solution 1**.

Comment: Solution 1 is vastly superior to solution 2, you shouldn't use the `ref` keyword if at all possible (same with `out`). For further reading, John Skeet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/635934/9363973

Comment: Completely agree. I would also recommend the solution 1.

Comment: Side note: in the solution **2** `out List<list_chart> lc` - we don't use `lc` but return it

Comment: Tried solution 1 but it didn't work. Still listchart1 has 0 recorf even lc has 100 records.

Comment: Does `dtMetric` has any record? As you want to add the record from `dtMetric` to `lc` with keeping it records intact?

Comment: Added Solution 1.1, check that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just modified LC by adding items it would have worked. By now you are replacing. this means assignList just has a different reference (to a new created list.)

Just return lc or use ref keyword before lc.

```
public List<list_chart> assignList(DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
        {
            lc = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
                  where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
                  orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
                  select new list_chart
                  {
                      SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
                      Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
                  }).ToList();
            return lc;
        }

//lc has 100 records but listchart1 still shows 0 after i call method.
listchart1 = assignList(dtMetric1, ucMetrics.CheckedItems[0].DisplayText);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are creating a new list in the method.

In order to support that, you need to use the `ref` keyword:

```
public void assignList(ref List<list_chart> lc, DataTable dtMetric, string metricname)
{
    lc = (from dr1 in dtMetric.AsEnumerable()
          where dr1.Field<string>("METRIC_NAME") == metricname
          orderby dr1["SAMPLE_TIME"] ascending
          select new list_chart
          {
              SAMPLE_TIME = dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"),
              Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("value")
          }).ToList();
}
//lc has 100 records but listchart1 still shows 0 after i call method.
assignList(ref listchart1, dtMetric1, ucMetrics.CheckedItems[0].DisplayText);
```

A better approach would be to return the List from the function.