# value type passed by reference in C#

Tags: c#

I am reading [microsoft documentation on parameter modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) and it says:

> When you pass a **value type** by reference:
>
> - If the method assigns the parameter to refer to a different object, those changes **aren't** visible from the caller.
> - If the method modifies the state of the object referred to by the parameter, those changes **are** visible from the caller.
>
> When you pass a **reference type** by reference:
>
> - If the method assigns the parameter to refer to a different object, those changes **are** visible from the caller.
> - If the method modifies the state of the object referred to by the parameter, those changes **are** visible from the caller.

And later, at "ref parameter modifier", it gives the following example code:

```
void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = refArgument + 44;
}

int number = 1;
Method(ref number);
Console.WriteLine(number);
// Output: 45
```

In this example number is a value-type variable, passed by reference to refArgument. In the method body refArgument gets a new value and then number gets a new value.

My question is why does number variable change? Above, regarding value types, it says

> If the method assigns the parameter to refer to a different object,
> those changes **aren't** visible from the caller.

Isn't `refArgument + 44` considered "a different object"?

Comment: Seems like a mistake in the documentation. Seeing the changes as caller is pretty much the whole point of calling by ref. 
The docu has an example like yours right below the statement you quoted.

Comment: The docs is wrong here, somewhere at the bottom there is a link where you should open an issue in their docs bug tracker. Do it, let them fix that to not to confuse readers.

Comment: My answer to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421426/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-to-c-s-param-in-a-method-signature/69421775#69421775) may help you understand things

Answer (score 3):

See also this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/32853) where someone also reported this as a documentation bug, but the documentation is written as intended.

`refArgument = refArgument + 44;` counts as "modifies the state of the object referred to by the parameter", apparently.

"Assigns the parameter to refer to a different object" would be assigning another `ref` thing to `refArgument`, like a `ref` to a field:

```
// in a class...
int somethingElse = 10;

void Method(ref int refArgument)
{
    refArgument = ref somethingElse;
}
```

When you assign an `int` to `refArgument`, that `int` is not a reference - it's just an `int`. The only sensible thing to do here is to set whatever `refArgument` is referring to, to that `int`. On the other hand, if you assign a reference to an `int` (`ref int`) to it, that changes what `refArgument` is referring to.

This is kind of similar to the behaviour of `*refArgument = *refArgument + 44;` vs `refArgument = &somethingElse;` in C.

Comment: The `ref somethingElse` doesn't look like valid C#. It could be a form of a pseudocode but why would the docs refer to something hypothetical that doesn't exist in the language? This would work in, say, C++ where you can create refs out of air, with `&` but as far as I know C# doesn't allow it. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @WiktorZychla This is [ref assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator#ref-assignment).

Comment: Ok, seems I've missed that part of language improvements. Consider my previous comment as invalid. Regards :)

Comment: Anyway, if this specific case was on mind of the person writing the docs, then in my opinion this is unfortunate and misleading. They seem to miss the simple, obvious case where you pass an int by-ref and just modify it, instead they refer to something that was even not valid C# until NET.Core.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I agree that it is a little misleading too. It might help to add an additional example in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Well no.

The thing is ref is used to "bind" values. So if you pass a Parameter using ref it doesnt just give the value of the variable to the parameter but it lets the parameter "reference" the original variable. That is the entire point of ref